# Run-time error '1004': Why?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem wtih my code. An error appears, that I cannot get rid off nor I have any clue why it appears. I hope that it is a silly mistake of a greenhorn like me and you are able to spot it easily. I do hope so.
The error is:
"Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"
Here is the code:

```
Sub CGT()

Dim Worksheet As Worksheets
startrow = Worksheets("GUTS").Cells(10, 1) 'Here I put 1
endrow = Worksheets("GUTS").Cells(11, 1)   'Here I put 1000    
For x = endrow To startrow Step -1

If Cells(x, "Q").Value = "Sale" Then

    If Cells(x, "D").Value = "1" Then

    For i = startrow To endrow

        If Cells(x - i, "R").Value = "1" Then
        Range("G" & x).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-i]C/R[-i]C[-1]*RC[-1]" 'Debugger highlights this line as bugged.. :(

        End If
    Next
    End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Thak you all in advance,
with best regards,
Artur.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: "Run-time error '1004':  
Application-defined or object-defined error"

Answer (score 2):

Because `i` is variable in your code you need to move it outside quotation marks when you create your formula. This should work:

```
Range("G" & x).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-" & i & "]C/R[-" & i & "]C[-1]*RC[-1]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems I feel so far are:

1> `startRow = Worksheets("GUTS").Cells(10, 1)` would create an object referring to a range (if used with "set") and not return the row of that range. I think you're looking for:

`startRow = Worksheets("GUTS").Cells(10, 1).Row`

```
endRow = Worksheets("GUTS").Cells(11, 1).Row
```

Although then you're probably just better of with saying startRow = 1 & endRow = 1000

2> `If Cells(x - i, "R").Value = "1"` produces an error when x & i are both the same number and hence refer to a row number '0', which is probably where the 'object undefined' might be coming from.